# Switch Select Query Case Column Value In A Table

Tags: sql-server, authentication, switch-statement

I want to do a thing like that in my stored procedure (in SQL Server): a parameter is coming from winforms side (User ID value) and in my stored procedure has a select query controlling the USER ID has Admin authentication (authorization number of admin is 666) from an `Authentication` table and such as 2 numbered user's 666 authorization type is true (1) then the select query will be like;

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
```

But if 2 numbered users 666 authorization type is false (0) then `Select` query will be like;

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE DEPTID = @DEPID
```

Is it possible in SQL Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_Proc
@ID VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [Authentication] WHERE UserID = @ID AND AuthType666 = 1)
   BEGIN
       SELECT * FROM TableName 
   END
  ELSE 
   BEGIN
      SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE <Condition>
   END

END
```

Comment: I see the thoughts in my brain is impossible. i was thinking i can do that like (if(value==xxx) THEN SELECT1 ELSE SELECT 2). I know this way of solve. But thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from table
where exists (select top 1 1 from Auth where userid = @ID and AuthType = 666) --user is admin
or deptid = @deptid --or limit results by department
```

**Update based on comment**

```
if (select top 1 1 from Auth where UserId=@ID and AuthType=666)
begin
    select something, somethingElse
    from someTable
end
else
begin
    select something, somethingElse
    from someTable
    where DeptId = @DeptId
end
```

NB: begin and end statements can be skipped if you only have 1 command (e.g. select statement) after the if/else - however I typically always use them just to ensure consistency / easy readability - but it's down to personal preference / your company's standards.

Comment: No no no. I have been misunderstood. I mean a contruction like that IF(SELECT AuthorizationSituation from Auth where UserID=@ID AND AuthType=666==True) THEN SELECT QUERY 1 ELSE SELECT QUERY 2

Comment: No worries - how about now?  NB: if you're selecting from the same table though you may find the original answer more maintainable.